# Xlib how to answer to wrong target in XSelectionRequestEvent?

Tags: c++, c, linux, clipboard, x11

I'm working on program for sending clipboard contents between different computers.

Now I'm stuck on processing request for sending data from clipboard to requestor on Linux with Xorg.

For example my program is own `image/bmp` data, but other program send me request for `image/png` that I'm just ignore. After approximately 30 seconds other program send me other request for `image/jpeg` and so on.

How to properly send answer to this wrong targets so other program wouldn't wait this 30 seconds timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just send `XSelectionEvent` with `property` field set to `None`.

```
// event is event that i responde

XEvent ev;
auto& sel_resp = ev.xselection;
sel_resp.type = SelectionNotify;
sel_resp.display = event.display;
sel_resp.requestor = event.requestor;
sel_resp.selection = event.selection;
sel_resp.target = event.target;
// Set property to None
sel_resp.property = None;
sel_resp.time = event.time;
XSendEvent( mDisplay, event.requestor, False, 0, &ev );
```